# How to select a list of names since with 3 letters?

Tags: mysql, select

How to select a list of names since with 3 letters ?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dDSS.png)

Comment: Could you add an example and paste the existing structure/expected output instead of just putting a link in the question?

Comment: what is `since with 3 letters` ?

Answer (score -1):

Do you want to get the records with `std_name` having 3 characters?

Try this query:

```
select * from student_tbl_mamedov where char_length(std_name)=3;
```

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not very clear. If you want to select only the first 3 letters of each name, then the [LEFT](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-left-function.php)  command would provide that:

```
SELECT LEFT([STD_NAME],3)
FROM STUDENT_TBL_Mamedov
```

If this is not what you are looking for, please restate your question and provide an example of the answer you require.